# Making this query in LINQ-SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I have `Employees`, `Groups`, and `EmployeeGroupFilters`.

An `Employee` has a `GroupID` with foreign key relationship.

An `EmployeeGroupFilter` has an Employee and Group ID. Each employee can filter which groups they do not want to see in the calendar.

Thus, if an `EmployeeGroupFilter` exists, that employee will not see that group.

I need a query that will return an `IEnumerable` of Group which will be the groups that are VISIBLE to the employee.

Ex: select all from Groups where group not in currentEmployee's Group filters.

Right now I can get all the employees filters like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<EmployeGroupFilter> GetAllByEmployee(
int employeeID)
{
    KezberPMDBDataContext db = new KezberPMDBDataContext();

    return from p in db.EmployeGroupFilters
           where p.EmployeID == employeeID
           select p;
}
```

I need something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<Group> GetAllVisibleEmployeeGroups(
int employeeID)
{
    KezberPMDBDataContext db = new KezberPMDBDataContext();

    return from p in db.Groups
           .......
           select p;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return from p in db.Groups
where !p.EmployeGroupFilters.Any(fil=>fil.EmployeeId == employeeID)
           select p;
```